# SSRS Report - Page Header Value from Grouped values

Tags: reporting-services

Problem:
I have report where I have table with grouping and page break after each instance of group value.
I want to have have different Page Header values as per Grouped values.

Attempts:
I have created Report Header and added expression in text box as ReportItems!TextBox1.Value
This gives me header but that does not change for each page.

I don't want to remove page header

Is it possible to have different headers on page?

Comment: Could you maybe create a new cell in the table, at the top of all other cells, that will span across the entire width of the table, but inside the group? That way each group will have its own "header". I am not saying the way you are currently working is wrong, it's just I am not sure how could it be done that way.

Comment: I got this. It worked in same way. I had missed to do grouping correctly. My bad. But thanks for your reply.